# How do you change the color of the WPF treeview arrow?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

How would I go about changing the color of the arrows that show up next to a treeviewitem in the wpf treeview? The arrows indicate whether the item is expanded or collapsed, I believe they are plus / minus signs with the windows xp theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embedded into the template, you could only change the color by copying the default Aero-Style for the control and changing the hard-coded value, or by drilling down the visual tree on-load to change it that way.

To get the default style & tenmplate [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (`Default WPF Themes` link).

Answer (score 0):

If you have MS Blend, you can achieve this by creating your own template.

Here is an example:
http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/06/29/styling-a-treeview-in-silverlight-and-blend-3.aspx